# How to use arrays to make a to do list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a to-do list in Javascript, and I can't figure out how to get the "tasks" I enter to appear on the list. I also need to be able to edit, delete, and update the tasks.

```js
var tasks = [];
var addTask;
var addAnother = "y";
var editTask;
var deleteTask;
var display = "";

display = prompt("Task List \n\n\n\n(1)Add Task\n(2)Delete Task\n(3) Edit Task \n(4)Quit");

while (addAnother == "y") {
  addTask = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a task"));
  tasks.push(addTask);
  addAnother = prompt("Do you want to add another task? y or n");
}

for (x = 0; x < addTask.length; x++) {
  display = display + tasks[x];
  alert(prompt("Task List\n" + addTask + "\n\n\n\n(1)Add Task\n(2)Delete Task\n(3) Edit Task\n(4)Quit"));
}
alert(display);
```

Comment: Why are you parsing your tasks as floats- in js arrays can, in fact, hold strings!

Answer (score 1):

Q: how to get the "tasks" I enter to appear on the list?

A: Exactly what you're doing: `tasks.push(addTask);`

Q: How do I generate a "task"?

A: There are a million different possibilities.

But typically, you'd want a "task" to be an object, built up of other objects or primitives.

EXAMPLE:

```
{
  description: 'Mow lawn',
  due: '12/31/2019',
  status: 'TBD'
}
```

In your scenario, you might want to prompt for "description", then "due date" and finally "status".  Then perhaps something like:

```
  myTask.description = description;
  myTask.due = dueDate;
  myTask.status = 'TBD';
  tasks.push(myTask);
```

Hopefully this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Though tasks usually contain metadata, like FoggyDay showed, if you do not care about this metadata you can just push the string the user inputs into the array. Before you were running a [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) on the input, which attempts to convert the string input into a floating point number.

```js
while(addAnother == "y")
{
    addTask = prompt("Enter a task");
    tasks.push(addTask);
    addAnother = prompt("Do you want to add another task? y or n"); 
}
```

Additionally, to enumerate your tasks, you should be using `tasks.length` instead of `addTask.length` as the condition in your for loop, and accessing the task in your array with `tasks[x]`:

```
for(x= 0; x < tasks.length; x++)
{
    display = display + tasks[x];
    alert(prompt("Task List\n" + tasks[x] + "\n\n\n\n(1)Add Task\n(2)Delete Task\n(3) Edit Task 
    \n(4)Quit"));
}
alert(display);
```

Now, if you have tasks "Mow lawn", "Do homework" and "Write program", this shows something along the lines of "Mow lawnDo homeworkWriteProgram", which is not the nicest output.

Fortunately, we can use the built-in function [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to separate the items in the output and merge the array, all in one step.

```js
display = tasks.join("\n");
for(x= 0; x < tasks.length; x++)
{
    alert(prompt("Task List\n" + tasks[x] + "\n\n\n\n(1)Add Task\n(2)Delete Task\n(3) Edit Task 
    \n(4)Quit"));
}
alert(display);
```